# C# Automatic designer code not generate in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I convert my solution from visual studio 2008 to 2010.
After this when i add or delete control from designer form, the automatic code is not generated. Also the warning is appeared:

> A custom tool 'SettingsSingleFileGenerator' is associated with file 'Properties>>\Settings.settings', but the output of the custom tool was not found in the project. You may try re-running the custom tool by right-clicking on the file in the Solution Explorer and choosing Run Custom Tool.

I have not Properties\Settings.settings file (and in vs 2008 i had not it).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What about any ideas?